# Error saving columns with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make **table** for **users**

The picture of the result and the columns that I want to add:

[image: phpmyadmin]

I can't see the an error and without an error message it's difficult to know what's wrong.

In my `php` scripts I'm able to get the error message via `mysql_error()`. But `myAdmin` shows nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about the problem? What happens when you press SAVE button? Is that text field not added?

Comment: @gibberish the columns not added and when i click on save i see this red bar like the picture

Comment: I believe the term 'id' is a protected value in phpmyadmin - try to change it to something like userId

Comment: @Grumpy yes you're right this error happened with me from 1 months but i forgot how to solve .... first i change it to userid or something like then it'll be save then i open structure and change it again to id :D

Comment: @smile so it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'ID' is restricted from MySQL - just change it to something like userId and it should work.